# How can I upload multiple images all at once?

Tags: 7, entities, media

Is there a way to upload multiple images all at the same time in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the [Plupload integration module](http://drupal.org/project/plupload). From the project page:

> Provides integration between for the Plupload widget to upload
>   multiple files and Drupal. Plupload is a GPL licensed multiple file
>   uploading tool that can present widgets in Flash, Gears, HTML 5,
>   Silverlight, BrowserPlus, and HTML4 depending on the capabilities of
>   the client computer.

Comment: plupload required node_gallery? http://drupal.org/project/node_gallery beacause node_gallery is not present for drupal 7!

Comment: the dev version can create a stand alone field.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Plup](http://drupal.org/project/plup) module.

> This module integrates a modern Plupload library with file field in Drupal 7. It provides a field widget for image field that allow user to upload multiple images at once using Plupload library. It depends on Libraries module.

Comment: You need to use the [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/ "Plupload") library for using the Plup module.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget) module.

> As an extension to the [Multiupload Filefield Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget) module, this module presents the same widget to Image fields.

Answer (score -3):

For an Image field, you can set the number of images you wish the user to upload.

[image: Image field settings. Highlighted select number of values]

(Image module must be enabled)

Comment: No, i request a multiple upload but the images must uploading all together and then they must see in the gallery, for example if i use media gallery it's impossible uploading most of one image and that is a difficult thing if i must create a gallery with 300 images for example!! Thank you for now